# NOT NULL constraint failed: - Django: IntegrityError

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-admin

The problem is  this:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPZPL.png)

And This is the models.py file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
# Create your models here.
User = get_user_model()
class BmiCal(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    weight = models.FloatField()
    height = models.FloatField()
    bmi = models.FloatField()
    date = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'bmi'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user + " : " +self.bmi
```

Should I change ForeignKey to OneToOneField or what.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove

```
class BmiAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('weight','height','bmi', 'date',)
```

You set fields u mentioned to readonly

Comment: Now i have this problem: NOT NULL constraint failed: bmi_calculator_bmical.user_id